# Architecture with infinite scroll user feed to avoid duplication (Vue & Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, data-structures, eloquent

I am creating a new app/product with Vue as the frontend & Laravel as the backend, which has a requirement for a social media type feature with posting & infinite feed, with things like friends, follows, topics, tags, visibility & other criteria that make up the basis for the “algorithm”.

I am currently using pagination to handle chunking the data, sending the first page with the initial request, then axios requests for additional pages as the user scrolls down.

I would like ideas/advice on architecturally or structurally how I should correctly handle the situation of the user seeing duplicate entries.

Example user story: User logs in and is redirect to their feed page. The response is sent back containing 20 posts (page 1) tailored to the specific criteria specified by & for that user. The user slowly scrolls down reading the posts as they go, during the time before they reach the trigger to grab the second page of posts, other users post 20 new posts that fit the criteria scrolling users feed criteria. On hitting the trigger, 20 more posts (page 2) are sent back, however due to the 20 new posts this means they are repeats of the same posts as page 1.

Now this example is just for context, in reality things are a lot more complex, but the same issue still exists that there is a relatively high probability of seeing duplicate posts in the same feed & I would like to know how is the best way to handle this solution, without adding too much complexity & overhead to the application.

I have considered a few concepts:

- A cache that holds the all the posts send to a user in a session & consults the cache before sending the posts & removes duplicates.
- Similar but excluding those posts from the query, making SQL server do the work
- real-time updates for new posts
- Simply with tracking time stamps of the posts fetched
- A combination of things.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: `Simply with tracking time stamps of the posts fetched` use this. the timestamp to user/session cache then do eloquent against it.

Comment: Or instead of timestamp, get the id of the last post fetch and eloquent against it..

Comment: ex: if last post's created_at is 2023/08/24 10:30, then on eloquent, do `where('create_at', '<=', timestamp)->orderby, limit, etc.

Comment: just a suggestion.

Comment: However, I would prefer to use `sort_id` if your PK is `uuid`, else use `id`